# Bytebuddy agent not getting loaded

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

I have a simple bytebuddy agent which records method entry/exit.
I run it as `mvn clean test -DargLine="-javaagent:$JAVA_AGENT_JAR"`

It works well for couple of my Java projects. However, when I tried it on few open source projects: [flink](https://github.com/apache/flink), [guava](https://github.com/google/guava), [dubbo](https://github.com/apache/dubbo) it dint work. I don't get any log trace to debug. It successfully runs the unit tests without executing any java-agent code. I am suspecting the agent is not even getting loaded. How do I debug/fix this issue?
`jdk: 1.8`
`bytebuddy verion:1.10.18`

Here is code snippet

```
@Override
  public void instrument(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    System.out.println("bytebuddy Instrmentation called");

    final Advice methodAdvice = Advice.to(MethodTracer.class);
    final Advice constructorAdvice = Advice.to(ConstructorTracer.class);


    ResettableClassFileTransformer agent = new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(new TracerLogger())  
        .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("com.examples.")) 
        .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
          @Override
          public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
            builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().method(ElementMatchers.isMethod(), methodAdvice));
            builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().constructor(ElementMatchers.isConstructor(), constructorAdvice));
            return builder;
          }
        })
        .installOn(instrumentation);
  }
```

Update-1: trying retransformation strategy, it still didn't work

```
            .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
                .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
                .type(matcher)
            .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
              @Override
              public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                  ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
                builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().method(
                    ElementMatchers.isMethod().and(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Test.class)), testMethodAdvice));
                builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().method(
                    ElementMatchers.isMethod().and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Test.class))),
                    methodAdvice));
                builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().constructor(
                    ElementMatchers.isConstructor().and(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Test.class)),
                    testConstructorAdvice));
                builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().constructor(
                    ElementMatchers.isConstructor().and(
                        ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Test.class))),
                    constructorAdvice));

                return builder;
              }
            })
            .installOn(instrumentation);
```

Update-2:
Using MAVEN_OPTS env variable solved the problem of loading the agent.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:$JAVA_AGENT=$CONFIG_FILE" 
mvn clean test -DargLine="-javaagent:$JAVA_AGENT=$CONFIG_FILE"
```

Comment: Is logger on the classpath and initialized? Try with `System.out.println` to exclude that possibility

Comment: @knittl I had tried `System.out.println`, still same issue. updated my code above. Thanks

Comment: Did you try registering an AgentBuilder.Listener to see if an error is raised?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter thanks for this amazing library and your invaluable support. I tried registering as `new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())`  It still dint print anything. any further clue ?

Comment: Then I assume that the class is already loaded at the time of execution. Have you tried registering a retransformation strategy?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter, I tried registering retransformation strategy, it still dint help. I have updated my post with the code snippet for retransformation strategy

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter any further clue?

Comment: You can enable verbose class loading and check if the class is loaded. It should definetly be logged in some for. You can also add a breakpoint to the executing class file transformer in the agent builder.